# how to increment values stored in an integer list java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, addition

I am trying to increment the value of an int variable stored in a list

```
List<Integer> unitsCounter = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

How would I do this? I have tried:

```
unitsCounter.get(0).add(i);
```

but this does not work and I can't think of anything else nor can I find search result relevant to my question.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: `unitsCounter.set(0,unitsCounter.get(0)+i)`

Comment: `unitsCounter.set(0,unitsCounter.get(0)+1)`

Comment: This works perfectly! is there a name for this kind of syntax "(0,unitsCounter.get(0)+1)" as i have not see this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unitsCounter.get(0)` returns an `Integer` which can be [unboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to an `int`, so [the additive operator `+`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) will work.

```
unitsCounter.set(0, unitsCounter.get(0) + i);
```

Then the result of `unitsCounter.get(0) + i` will be autoboxed back to be stored in `unitsCounter` at index `0`.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly fancy way to do it would be:

```
unitCounter.subList(0, 1).updateAll(v -> v + 1);
```

But this is probably more convoluted than:

```
unitCounter.set(0, unitCounter.get(0) + i);
```

An alternative would be to use an element type designed for counting things, e.g. `LongAdder`:

```
List<LongAdder> unitCounter = ...

unitCounter.get(0).add(i);
```

Comment: how would I add to LongAdder?

Comment: @DarthBusiness with the `increment` method (to add 1) or `add` (to add an arbitrary amount).